# "Extra" nesting in MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have some document stored in MongoDB (2.4.9) with and array if documents field:

```
{
    "_id" : "some id",
    "class" : "somevalue",
    ...
    "externalAlarmDefinition" : [ 
        {
            "idx" : 1,
            "inputId" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "idx" : 2,
            "inputId" : 2
        }, 
        ...
        {
            "idx" : 6,
            "inputId" : 7
        }
    ]
}
```

For some reason, when I query this object I get `BsonElement` who's value is a `BsonArray` with one element - that element in turn is another `BsonArray` which contains the actual `BsonDocuments`. See image for the structure:
[image: double nesting]

Does this make sense? I expected that the value of the `BsonElement` would be a `BsonArray` with the 6 `BsonDocument`s.

Am I missing something - can someone explain this?

I am using Mongo Driver 1.9.1.221 that I got using nuget